# for loop C work weird?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a problem with for loop in C.
The purpose of the program is to find prime numbers in known quantity k.
Here is my program:

```
 unsigned int i, k, j;
    unsigned long int prime;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    printf("How many prime numbers do you want to print out in order? "); scanf_s("%u", &k);
        printf("%u fist prime numbers are: ", k);
        i = 1;
        prime = 2;
        while (i <= k)
        {
                for (j = 2; j <= prime; j++)
                {
                    if (prime % j == 0)
                    {
                        if (j == prime && prime != 2)
                        {
                            printf("%lu, ", prime);
                            i++;
                        }
                        prime++;
                        j = 2;
                    }
                }
        }
        _getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

And when I run the program, it returns infinite sequence of numbers. But if I adds "else j++;" like this:

```
for (j = 2; j <= prime; j++)
                {
                    if (prime % j == 0)
                    {
                        if (j == prime && prime != 2)
                        {
                            printf("%lu, ", prime);
                            i++;
                        }
                        prime++;
                        j = 2;
                    }
                               else j++;
                }
```

Then the program will work out properly. I think this is kinda weird and can't explain why?

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad English).

Comment: Presumably something to do with your resetting j to 2...

Comment: Why do you have `j = 2;` inside the loop?

Comment: And you've walked thru it in the debugger?

Comment: Why is there no `break` after `i++`?

Comment: @devnull: It's due to my algorithm, when the prime increase its value by 1, the j must be reset...

Comment: @kfsone: Because i'm making a list of prime numbers (not just only one prime number) following to the request from the user...?

Comment: "break" exits the current loop. Don't you want to exit the for loop and return to the while loop at that point?

Comment: There should be break statement after 
    if (j == prime && prime != 2)
    {
        printf("%lu, ", prime);
        i++;
        break;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, the problem was caused by your having no "break" in the for-loop to cause it to return to the outer while loop when you detected a valid divisor.

This was compounded by your poor use of variable names confusing you - your original code appears to be confused about what "j" and "prime" are.

Here I've refactored your code to be cleaner and give a significant performance increase for large prime searches:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FALSE (0)
#define TRUE (!(FALSE))

int main()
{
    int numPrimes = 0;
    int candidate, divisor;
    int isPrime;
    printf("How many prime numbers do you want to print out in order? ");
    scanf("%u", &numPrimes);
    printf("\n%u first prime numbers are:\n", numPrimes);

    if (numPrimes > 0) {
        printf("2, ");
        --numPrimes;
    }

    // we only need to test odd numbers.
    for (candidate = 3; numPrimes > 0; candidate += 2) {
        // N / (N/2) + 1 is always < 1, so we only have to test half the values.
        // we also only need to test odd divisors
        isPrime = TRUE;
        for (divisor = 3; divisor <= candidate / 2; ++divisor) {
            // it's not prime if testNumber divides in
            if (candidate % divisor == 0) {
                isPrime = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            printf("%lu, ", candidate);
            --numPrimes;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo here: http://ideone.com/yrUPBy

Which gladly tells me

```
How many prime numbers do you want to print out in order? 
1000 first prime numbers are:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 
37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 
79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 
...
7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 7841, 
7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has `j <= prime` as the end condition, meaning the last value of `j` will be equal to `prime`. In that case `(prime % j == 0)` will always be true.

When you add the extra `j++` you're skipping half the values of `j` which accidentally skips past the problem. The program still isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When the program prints the prime `3`, the variables have the following values:

```
i = 1
j = 3
prime = 3
```

Then you increment `i` and `prime`, and set `j = 2`, so it's:

```
i = 2
j = 2
prime = 4
```

Now you return to the top of the loop, which does `j++`:

```
i = 2
j = 3
prime = 4
```

Since `j <= prime`, the loop continues. Since `prime % j` is not `0`, it skips the body of that `if`, and returns to the top of the loop, which increments `j` again:

```
i =2
j = 4
prime = 4
```

This time `prime % j == 0`, so it prints `prime`, even though it's not actually a prime number.

This keeps happening for every value of `prime`.

When you add `j++` to the `else` clause, it causes `j` to be incremented twice in the failing case. So it goes from 3 to 5, and never makes it to the case where `j == prime` and it prints the number. Then `j <= prime` fails, so the `for` loop terminates.